# Delaunay Triangulation on sphere (unstructured long lat grid)

Tags: python, scipy, delaunay, scipy-spatial, geoviews

I work with an unstructured grid of weather data, and I'm trying to plot it. For that I use the Delaunay triangulation.

```
def triangulate(vertices, x="Longitude", y="Latitude"):
    """
    Generate a triangular mesh for the given x,y,z vertices, using Delaunay triangulation.
    For large n, typically results in about double the number of triangles as vertices.
    """
    triang = Delaunay(vertices[[x, y]].values)
    return pd.DataFrame(triang.simplices, columns=['v0', 'v1', 'v2'])

x = ((np.rad2deg(data.clon) - 180) % 360) - 180
y = np.rad2deg(data.clat)
    
value = data[attr][t][i]
pts = np.stack((x, y, value)).T
verts = pd.DataFrame(pts, columns=['Longitude', 'Latitude', 'value'])
triangulate(verts)
```

I use geoviews to plot the trimesh in a NorthPolarStereo projection. There I have the issue that the triangles don't overlap due to the periodic behavior of the sin/cos.

[image: Here you can see the missing overlap as a gap in the rendered Data]

Is there a way to modify the Delaunay triangulation that the triangles overlap at the 0° / 360° area?

The plotting is done by the following:

```
trimesh = rasterize(gv.TriMesh((g.tris, hv.Points(g.verts, vdims='value')), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree()))
    
(trimesh).opts(
                cmap='Greys',
                fig_size=180,
                aspect=1,
                projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
```

Thanks for any advise. In case more code is needed let me know :)

Comment: If I highlight the `Delaunay Triangulation on sphere` part from the title and use a popular search engine, there seem to be some results.

Comment: @tevemadar I didn't find any that would help me so far. The Voroni triangulation would represent the data in a wrong way, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Some libraries implement direct support for a triangulation over the surface of a sphere. But absent that, one work-around solution is to create a planar domain that extends larger than 180w and 180e, say from -360 and +360. You could include multiple vertices for your set of data points. A point located at longitude -90 would also be added as a vertex at longitude 270. You could then conduct whatever processing you need to do over the entire Delaunay triangulation and clip the results.

I will attach a picture from my employer's Dispatch Weather Client (DWC) product that shows this approach for surface temperature data from weather-reporting stations. This example extends the domain across longitudes. For your purposes, you could use the same idea extending data beyond the polar latitudes.

[image: Mercator Projection for Global METARs]

Updated Answer 21 Oct 2022

I am not familiar with the API you are using.  So, reading your code, I am not completely sure what you're doing. But based on your picture, it looks like you might be constructing your Delaunay mesh from latitude/longitude coordinates and then applying the Polar Stereographic projection over the results.  If that is a correct assessment, then I think you will get better results if you perform the map projection (from lat/lon to Cartesian x/y) first and then build your mesh.  This approach will automatically get rid of the seam that you are seeing in your plot.  And, better yet, it will convert the non-isotropic latitude/longitude coordinates to a more conformal Cartesian coordinate system.  Results from the Delaunay tend to be more accurate when its input coordinates are uniform in their representation of distance.   Here's a second picture.  Because the lat/lon coordinates are projected to the Polar Stereographic, the second mesh I produced doesn't even need the redundant vertices.

[image: Delaunay constructed over projected coordinates]

Here's a bit of code for the Polar Stereographic, spherical case:

```
public void transform(
    boolean southPole, double centralMeridian,
    double latitude, double longitude,
    double[] output) {

double earthRadius = 6378137.0;  // WGS84 semi-major axis
double phi = Math.toRadians(latitude);
double delta = Math.toRadians(longitude - centralMeridian);
if (southPole) {
    delta = -delta;
    phi = - phi;
}
double p = 2 * tan(PI / 4 - phi / 2) * earthRadius;
output[0] = p * sin(delta);   // X coordinate
output[1] = -p * cos(delta);  // Y coordinate

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you have a code sample you would share? And which libraries do you use for that?

Comment: The API I use for the Delaunay is from the Tinfour library on Github at https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour.  I didn't mention Tinfour in my original answer because it is written in Java and you are working in Python. The interpolation I perform over the surface uses  Tinfour's Natural Neighbor Interpolation.  There is a Java map-projection package called proj4j that's quite good, though I just implemented the Stereographic using a bit of trig.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help so far! Do you have an Idea how to do the projection, somehow I'm struggling with the  cartopy and scipy combination...

Comment: See if you can find  "Map Projections Used by the U.S. Geological Survey"  Geological Survey Bulletin 1532, Second Edition, 1984 by John P. Synder, page 104, or Snyder's "Map Projections a Working Manual".  Those are the two go-to standards for map projections.

Comment: Thanks :) I think I struggle more with the implementation so far. But I'll have a look :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems, that the problem can't be solved with a rotation or projection to cartesian coords. I think I'll need to figure out how to add a cyclic point to an unstructured grid.